# How to add active class on current url menu item with Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, menu, alpine.js

```
<li><a href="/" class="nav-item active">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about" class="nav-item">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/services" class="nav-item">Services</a></li>
```

Lets say we have a navigation and currently we are on Home page (Path = '/') what i want is to add the same active class to about (Path = '/about') when i visit About Page using **Alpine.js**

**Expected Output Will be**

```
<li><a href="/" class="nav-item">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/about" class="nav-item active">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact" class="nav-item">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/services" class="nav-item">Services</a></li>
```

I already searched on Google but only found on click with Alpine.js. I already have the submenu
Example:

```
 <ul x-show="linkActive" x-cloak x-collapse.duration.300ms class="text-gray-400">
                <!-- start::Submenu link -->
                <li
                    class="cursor-pointer py-2 pl-10 pr-6 transition duration-200 hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-30 text-gary-200 hover:text-white">
                    <a href="{{route('admin.products.index')}}" class="flex items-center">
                        <span class="mr-2 text-sm">&bull;</span>
                        <span class="overflow-ellipsis">All Products</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end::Submenu link -->

                <!-- start::Submenu link -->
                <li
                    class="cursor-pointer py-2 pl-10 pr-6 transition duration-200 hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-30 text-gary-200 hover:text-white">
                    <a href="./pages/email/viewMessage.html" class="flex items-center">
                        <span class="mr-2 text-sm">&bull;</span>
                        <span class="overflow-ellipsis">Category</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end::Submenu link -->

                <!-- start::Submenu link -->
                <li
                    class="cursor-pointer py-2 pl-10 pr-6 transition duration-200 hover:bg-black hover:bg-opacity-30 text-gary-200 hover:text-white">
                    <a href="./pages/email/newMessage.html" class="flex items-center">
                        <span class="mr-2 text-sm">&bull;</span>
                        <span class="overflow-ellipsis">Tags</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- end::Submenu link -->
            </ul>
```

Comment: What is your backend? How do you render a page?

Comment: I made a menu just like what you're trying to do and I used the Persist plugin to keep track of the last menu item requested, but that falls apart when you load a different page outside of menu navigation. so, kind of like Dauros may be alluding to, you may want to just add the class on the server side. On the client side, if you can track the current URL in a variable, then just bind the class and check that variable. My menu was an Alpine template iterated x-for item in items with `x-bind:class="[ (currentMenuItem === item.id )?'active':'' ] "`

Comment: @Dauros i am using it with Laravel and Tailwind

Comment: Then you can add the `active` class on the backend since the navigation is handled by Laravel.